# How to replace the column value with value from other connected table

Tags: sql, postgresql

The code below is my query code of postgresql schema views.

Please assuming this a library table, which is a book list and you have some defined tags can apply on the book itself, and every book will be devided into one category.

```
CREATE VIEW tagging_books AS
SELECT tags."TagName", books."BookISBN", books."BookName", books."BookCategoryID"
FROM library
    INNER JOIN tags on library."TagName_id" = tags."id"
    INNER JOIN books on library."BookISBN_id" = books."id"
    ORDER BY tags."id"
```

The schema views inside db will looks like this:

```
/tags.TagName   /books.BookISBN      /books.BookName    /books.BookCategoryID
Python          ISBN 957-208-570-0   Learn Python       1
```

And the BookCategoryID from table "books" is actually a foreign key of table "category", the table looks like this:

```
/category
BookCategoryID   CategoryName
1                Toolbook
```

I wonder that, is there anyway to replace the books."BookCategoryID" field to category."CategoryName" by query code? Like the example below.

```
/tags.TagName   /books.BookISBN      /books.BookName    /category.CategoryName
Python          ISBN 957-208-570-0   Learn Python       Toolbook
```

Since they are connected with each other, I think they can definitely being replaced, but I don't know how to do... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include `category.name`, simply join with table category on the foreign-key constraint like:

```
select category.name, books.*
from books
join category on books.BookCategoryID = category.BookCategoryID
```

You can add it to your view creation as well:

```
CREATE VIEW tagging_books AS
SELECT tags.TagName, books.BookISBN, books.BookName, category.name as "CategoryName"
FROM library
    JOIN tags on library.TagName_id = tags.id
    JOIN books on library.BookISBN_id = books.id
    JOIN category on books.BookCategoryID = category.BookCategoryID
ORDER BY tags.id
```

Comment: thanks! May I ask if it is possible to add this into the already existed query code I have above? or execute another query code after the first one to update the original view?